# Printing File list

Tags: java, list, file, directory

I've got some problems trying to print the list of available directories.
Here's my code with comments:

```
File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));
System.out.println(f.list().toString()); //the output here is absolutely incorrect
```

This is the output

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@1540e19d
```

Comment: define "absolutely incorrect" for us please.

Comment: Ok. It's [Ljava.lang.String;@1540e19d

Comment: You're getting an array of String. Iterate through that array, or print it out with `System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(f.list()));`

Comment: Ok. As I understand f.list().toString returns an array of strings. But what does the f.list() return?

Comment: No, f.list() returns the array. What you're seeing is the typical `toString()` output of any array of String. `[` means array. Then you see the class name for String, then the array's hashcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find directories, you need to filter the list. listFiles() is a better method to use as it returns a list of File objects rather than String, this is ultimately more powerful and allows things like testing if the "file" is a directory which I believe you're trying to do.

```
File home = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));

for (File file : home.listFiles()) {
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        System.out.println(file);
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can use a FileFilter in listFiles(), this will return a primitive array of File, which you can change to a List with Arrays.asList

```
List<File> directories = Arrays.asList(home.listFiles(new FileFilter() {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File pathname) {
        return pathname.isDirectory();
    }
}));
```

Regarding the issue of the "incorrect" output [Ljava.lang.String;@1540e19d, this is normal for printing out primitive arrays, unlike Collection types which typically have a nice toString() implemention. You can use the utility method [java.util.Arrays.toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(java.lang.Object[])) to "pretty print" each element.

If you require a recursive listing I'd consider using the newer java.nio.Files.walk() functionality rather than writing your own recursive method.

```
List<Path> paths = Files.walk(home.toPath()).filter(new Predicate<Path>() {
            @Override
            public boolean test(Path path) {
                return path.toFile().isDirectory();
            }
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or more concisely with Java 8 closures.

```
List<Path> paths = Files.walk(home.toPath()).filter((path) -> path.toFile().isDirectory()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Best answer of the bunch. 1+

Answer (score 4):

Your output, [Ljava.lang.String;@1540e19d, is the typical toString() output of any array of String. [ means array. Then you see the class name for String, then the array's hashcode.

You're getting an array of String. Iterate through that array in a for loop

```
for (String fileName : f.list()) {
    System.out.println(fileName);
}
```

or print it out with

```
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(f.list()));
```

---

The key is to use the [File API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html) as it will tell you what the `File#list()` will return, here an array of String.

Comment: @MaximGotovchits: the key is to use the API as it will tell you what the `File#list()` will return, here an array of String.

Answer (score 0):

this ll print number files as well as list the file in current directory :

```
File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));
System.out.println(f.list().length);

for (String fileName : f.list()) {
    System.out.println(fileName);
}
```

**if you want to list files with `subdirectory` and it's file then :**

```
public void listFiles( String path ) {

        File root = new File( path );
        File[] list = root.listFiles();

        for ( File f : list ) {
            if ( f.isDirectory() ) { // check that if current instance is file or directory
                listFiles( f.getAbsolutePath() );
                System.out.println( "Dir:" + f.getAbsoluteFile() );
            }
            else {
                System.out.println( "File:" + f.getAbsoluteFile() );
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        fw.listFiles("c:\\" );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way

```
File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));
  String tok[]=f.list();
  for(String s:tok){
      System.out.println(s);
  }
```

Alternatively you can use `java.util.Arrays` to convert `String array` returned by `f.list()` to string as:

```
Arrays.toString(f.list());
```